# How to choose the adequate Linux distribution for a given hardware set up?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, distribution-choice

We all have a common issue whereby there is an old PC lying around and we want to revive it using a secure Linux distro (vs. using the un-updated native OS, likely Windows) that is both user-friendly and snappy.

Use case:

> I have an old Dell Latitute 131 L ([specs here](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/en/spec_latit_131l_en.pdf)). I am considering
>   dual-boot installing Linux (it already has XP).

Specifications

> - 256 DDR2 RAM
> - 50+ gig free disk space
> - AMD Turion 64 X2 (64-bit dual-core mobile CPU) 1.6 GHz

How do we know which distribution to choose? Are there any risks to picking older versions of a given distribution?

Comment: If you can afford $10-$20 for another 1-2GB of memory, you won't have to make any compromises on which distro to use.

Comment: This is an opinionated Q, please refrain from asking these types of Q's. See the help for more info on appropriate Q's for the site.http://unix.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @slm I was afraid of that :-) I know opinion-based questions are very frowned upon in SO but I figured I would chance it.

Comment: Yeah I would try and reform the Q, perhaps there's a way to appease the rules and get your Q asked in some form.

Comment: I just did that. Actually what would be great is some Linux wiki with a matrix of hardware requirements to Linux distro possibility...

Comment: Just an update - I tried Linux Mint 12. I saw the splash screen and then all I saw was a black screen with very thin stripes of red blue and green repeated at a regular interval. I take it that distro didn't support the screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity & easy install, you could use Linux Mint or Ubuntu; and just install a simpler (LXDE) Desktop Environment.  This will speed up the 'snappiness' of the GUI, while sticking with a modern (and theoretically more secure) distro.

As always, performance largely depends on what you want to use it for.  The above recommendation of a RAM upgrade is definitely the best single, reasonably priced addition to speed things up quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Two good, lightweight Ubuntu-based distos are [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). You should look into those. 
If you are feeling adventurous you can try Arch Linux. Arch gives you a bare minimum environment, so you will have to build your own system from the ground up. This requires a little more knowledge, but [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) has a good guide to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried Xubuntu in the past and didn't like the UI. I will look into Xubuntu. I'm doing this for a friend who is not tech savvy so I take it Arch Linux is off the table. Thanks again.